# Parsing HTML with RegEx - SO tags

Tags: html, tags

WAIT! I am not asking how to Parsing HTML with RegEx... I am not Chuck Norris.

There's this question in SO: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

And the first answer, with 4430 upvotes has some pretty strange HTML in it. The question is: How did he do it? I can look in the page source, but how did he do it using StackOverflow's tags?

I feel I could post this in Meta, but anyone would know how to use SO tags, right? Right?

Comment: I think they are just a nice collection of unicode characters and diacritics. But anyhow, if this question should be asked at all, it should be asked at Meta.

Comment: Yes, they are simply multil͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨine unicode characters. It has nothing to do with Stack Overflow tag͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆s.

Comment: Hey, you did it. How did you do it?

Comment: Well, at the end of the day they're unicode characters, so... Copy & Paste.

Comment: TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ